# Codeigniter strip image EXIF data

Tags: image, codeigniter, resize, exif, gd2

I am doing image upload and resizing using the gd2 image library.

The image EXIF data is rotating my vertical pictures on resize. Is there a way to stop the image from rotating? or strip the exif data in php?

Comment: I'm having the same problem -- could you post your solution if you happen to have one?

Answer (score 1):

Barring learning the JPEG format and figuring out how to remove EXIF bit by bit...

You can use the GD library.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php should do it.